# How to add something to a lot of line from a file until condition is met?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, if-statement, printing

**So I have a text file that looks like this:**

'''

Name: John

Last Name: Brown

'''

**All I want is to print something in the beginning of the ''' quotation marks and in the beginning of all the lines that follow UNTIL I read another set of quotation marks.**

**This is what I've been trying to code:**

```
for line in infile:
    if line.find("'''") !=-1:        
            print("PROTECTED",line.rstrip(),end = "")
```

**How I want it to look like:**

PROTECTED '''

PROTECTED Name:John

PROTECTED Last Name:Brown

PROTECTED '''

**I have more data after that but I can't figure out how to only put PROTECTED on those lines.**

**I think my for loop is wrong a little bit and I need help with that.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a tag to indicate that whether you have found the first ''', if you found that, then set the tag and add "PROTECTED" for all lines after that until you find another '''. Below is code sample:

```
firstPosFound = False

for line in infile:
    if line.find("'''") !=-1 and firstPosFound == False:
        print("PROTECTED",line.rstrip(),end = "")
        firstPosFound = True
        continue

    if line.find("'''") !=-1 and firstPosFound == True:
        print("PROTECTED",line.rstrip(),end = "")
        firstPosFound = False
        continue

    if firstPosFound == True:
        print("PROTECTED", line.rstrip(), end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `line.find` to check if a string contains another string, python makes that quite easy:

`if "'''" in line:`

As long as `'''` is on a line alone, you can just check if the line is equal to `'''`, and then toggle a boolean value to print `PROTECTED` before each line.

```
intext = """other text
'''
Name: John
Last Name: Brown
'''
some other text"""

protec = False
for line in intext.split("\n"):
    if "'''" == line: #on a line which has triple quotations
        protec = not protec #toggle boolean
        print("PROTECTED", line.rstrip())
    else: 
        if protec: #if text is between '''
            print("PROTECTED", line.rstrip())
```

Output:

> PROTECTED '''
>
> PROTECTED Name: John
>
> PROTECTED Last Name: Brown
>
> PROTECTED '''

Comment: I tried something like this but got an error I can't really understand that error: def main():

    file = open("data.py","r")
    infile = file.readlines()

    protec = False
    for line in infile.split("\n"):
        if "'''" == line: #on a line which has triple quotations
            protec = not protec #toggle boolean
            print("PROTECTED", line.rstrip())
        else: 
            if protec: #if text is between '''
                print("PROTECTED", line.rstrip())
main()

Comment: Never mind I figured it out!! Thanks for the example tho !! Really much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a flag variable:

```
inside_quotes = False
for line in infile:
    if (line.find("'''") !=-1):
        print("PROTECTED",line.rstrip(),end = "")
        inside_quotes = not inside_quotes
        continue
    if inside_quotes:
        print("PROTECTED",line.rstrip(),end = "")
```

There are probably better ways, this is just the first method I thought of